# ASP.NET MVC request processing and response generating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand what exact method is generating view? As I've understood when we're sending `http`- request to a server the following subsequent of actions is executed:

1. Router is creating `ControllerContext` class instance
2. Router is creating a corresponding controller class instance
3. Router is invoking a corresponding controller's action.
4. After the action method return an instance `actResult` of `ActionResult` the `actResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)` is invoked.

Question: Is my understanding of the request processing true? And I don't understand what exactly generate a response text? I'm interested in what method generates the response body?

Comment: What do you need this information for? We may can help you better or suggest alternatives if you specify the use case of this. Or is it just for your interest?

Comment: @chrfin I want to understand how does ASP.NET MVC works. In particullar, I don't understand who is rendering view? Can you help me?

Comment: "I want to understand how ASP.NET MVC works" is a question much too broad for [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more about this [HERE](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/TbR0041112-Asp.net-MVC-Request-Life-Cycle.html) or [HERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/Asp-Net-mvc-request-life-cycle/).

To address your specific question:
The action returns a result. If this result is a view result the appropriate view engine is selected and then this engine will render the view.

Details from my first link:

**View Result**

> The action method receives user input, prepares the appropriate response data, and then executes the result by returning a result
>   type. The result type can be ViewResult, RedirectToRouteResult,
>   RedirectResult, ContentResult, JsonResult, FileResult, and
>   EmptyResult.

**View Engine**

> The first step in the execution of the View Result involves the selection of the appropriate View Engine to render the View Result. It
>   is handled by IViewEngine interface of the view engine. By default
>   Asp.Net MVC uses WebForm and Razor view engines. You can also register
>   your own custom view engine to your Asp.Net MVC application as shown
>   below:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
 //Remove All View Engine including Webform and Razor
 ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
 //Register Your Custom View Engine
 ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
 //Other code is removed for clarity
}
```

**View**

> Action method may returns a text string,a binary file or a Json formatted data. The most important Action Result is the ViewResult, which renders and returns an HTML page to the browser by using the current view engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've one doubt: what is the purpose of `ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)` method of `ActionResult` class?